# How can I do a Unit Testing in KnockoutJS with QUnit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, knockout.js, qunit

I have this ViewModel (short) with KnockoutJS and I need to make a Unit Test using QUnit but I have this error message when i running my test.

ViewModel:

```
var modeloContratacion;//NOSONAR

define(['jquery', 'compartidas'], function($, compartidas) {

    var _modeloContratacion = function() {

    this.ObtenerPopUpARC = function(){
            const dfdPopUp = $.Deferred();

            const _resAccesoServicioObtenerPopUpARC =
            compartidas.InvocarServicio(this.Configuracion.RutaServicioCentral() + 'catalogos/obten-popup', '', 'GET', '');

            _resAccesoServicioObtenerPopUpARC.done(function(jsonR){
                dfdPopUp.resolve(jsonR);
            });

            return dfdPopUp.promise();
        };
 };

    modeloContratacion = new _modeloContratacion();
    return modeloContratacion;
});
```

Unit Test:

```
const modeloContratacion = require('../src/main/webapp/Models/ModeloContratacion.js');

QUnit.module('modeloContratacion');

QUnit.test('Mensaje PopUp', function (assert) {
    return modeloContratacion.ObtenerPopUpARC().then(function (result) {
        assert.equal(result.control.codigoRespuesta, 0);
    });
});
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a4yw.png)

What i can do?
Or can i use another framework to do Unit Test?

I'm trying to do a Unit Test